# Using the Bellman-Ford algorithm from petgraph

Tags: algorithm, rust, bellman-ford, petgraph

I would like to use the Bellman-Ford algorithm from the petgraph crate. Here is a very simple sample program which does not compile:

```
extern crate petgraph;

use petgraph::prelude::*;
use petgraph::dot::{Dot, Config};
use petgraph::algo::bellman_ford;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");

    let mut deps = Graph::<&str, u64>::new();
    let a = deps.add_node("later");
    let b = deps.add_node("hello");
    deps.update_edge(a, b, 5);
    deps.update_edge(b, a, 10);

    let result = bellman_ford(deps, NodeIndex::new(0));
}
```

When I compile this program I get this error message:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `petgraph::Graph<&str, f64>: petgraph::visit::IntoNodeIdentifiers` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:16:18
   |
16 |     let result = bellman_ford(deps, NodeIndex::new(0));
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `petgraph::visit::IntoNodeIdentifiers` is not implemented for `petgraph::Graph<&str, f64>`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <&'a petgraph::Graph<N, E, Ty, Ix> as petgraph::visit::IntoNodeIdentifiers>
   = note: required by `petgraph::algo::bellman_ford`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `petgraph::Graph<&str, f64>: petgraph::visit::IntoEdges` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:16:18
   |
16 |     let result = bellman_ford(deps, NodeIndex::new(0));
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `petgraph::visit::IntoEdges` is not implemented for `petgraph::Graph<&str, f64>`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <&'a petgraph::Graph<N, E, Ty, Ix> as petgraph::visit::IntoEdges>
   = note: required by `petgraph::algo::bellman_ford`
```

Comment: `the following implementations were found: <&'a petgraph ...` Try to replace `deps` with `&deps`

Answer (score 3):

From what I have gathered, the implemented Bellman-Ford algorithm works with floats, not integers.

Using floats instead of the `u64` and referencing `deps` later does the trick:

```
use petgraph::algo::bellman_ford;

fn main() {
    let mut deps = Graph::<&str, f64>::new();
    let a = deps.add_node("later");
    let b = deps.add_node("hello");
    deps.update_edge(a, b, 5.0);
    deps.update_edge(b, a, 10.0);

    let result = bellman_ford(&deps, NodeIndex::new(0));
    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```